# Same Ubuntu image fetched for docker machine and docker container but more binaries are available in docker-machine

Tags: docker, containers

I created a container and logged in

```
docker run -it -d ubuntu bash
```

checked `fdisk -l`  its **NOT** available.

But when I create a machine using:

```
docker-machine create -d "virtualbox" --swarm-image "ubuntu"  dev3
```

The command `fdisk` is **available** in the machine.

Question: I guess binaries comes from image, how this is happening? and how can I add `fdisk` without creating a custom image or installing it after container creation.

**Same host**

Answer (score 2):

Your two commands are doing completely different things.

In the first case, you're pulling down the `ubuntu` docker image and starting a **container**.

In the second case, you're building a **virtual machine** in Virtualbox using a VM image named `ubuntu`. This is a completely different operation and the `ubuntu` vm image has *nothing* to do with the `ubuntu` container image.  The minimal set of packages required to actually boot a machine is substantially larger than that required to start a container, so it's no surprise that the virtual machine has packages you don't find in the container image.

For example, a container doesn't interact with block devices so there is no need to have `fdisk` installed. If you really need `fdisk` in a container image (which, again, is unlikely, although there are some use cases where that makes sense), you would build a custom image from a Dockerfile.  E.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu:eoan
RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install fdisk
```

Comment: So, for example If I am responsible for a particular image in dockerhub I shall have to create different images for VM and containers?

Comment: Docker doesn't have anything to do with vms. If you are responsible for a particular image in Docker hub, that is **only** a container image. The `docker-machine` tool is used to create virtual machines on which you run docker. It's not meant as a general deployment tool.

Comment: I want to understand from where docker machine is getting that binary, could you point me to some link?

Comment: I haven't worked with docker machine (I run docker natively on Linux), so I'm not sure from where it pulls vm images.

Comment: Then question remains... I am fetching the image from a docker.io `docker.io/xx/xx/x` and used same url in case of both machine and container. So Image is same.

Comment: The image is not the same. As I've tried to explain in my answer, you **cannot** boot a docker-machine virtual machine (or **any** virtual machine) with a container image. They are different things with different purposes and different requirements.

Comment: So we are saying that `docker-machine create -d "virtualbox" --swarm-image "docker.io/openstackhelm/nova:rocky-ubuntu_xenial" machine1` And 
`docker run -it --privileged -d docker.io/openstackhelm/nova:rocky-ubuntu_xenial bash` are fetching two different images? I highly doubt, everyone is maintaining 2 different images in dockerhub. What I think, is `docker-machine` add some binaries on top of the existing ones. Not sure.